# Bad question used as test in review queue gives me review ban

Tags: discussion, review-queues, disputed-review-audits, review-suspension

https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/11476200

This question is too broad or opinion based and should definitely not be used as a test for a "Looks OK" question in my opinion.

Now I get a ban from reviewing for 7 days because I did not click "Looks OK".

Is this question really fine and should be used as a test?

Comment: Well, it is a bad review audit for sure, but failing a *single* audit will not cause you to be banned from reviewing. You must have failed other audits over the past week or so.

Comment: How are questions picked for review audit?

Comment: A cadre of unicorns picks them at random from our Infinite Bad Question Pool™. I believe the Community user is also responsible for generating fake, garbage edits that in turn serve as audits.

Comment: I dont know why this is downvoted. The question is utter garbage.

Comment: I also want to know how this could possibly be used as a known-good audit when there have been close votes on it since the day it was posted

Comment: Raymond's close vote had aged away. It was sitting as a 5-score question (+6/-1). Apparently the algorithm for choosing audits doesn't take erstwhile close votes into account.

Comment: @CodyGray Thats not in line with what has been said about chosing known good audits before. Among the criteria was that the question never recieved down or close votes...

Comment: Agreed. I unsuspended your review rights. Cheers.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Asking purely out of curiosity of how the system works, not intending to disparage the OP, but if you restore review rights, do previously failed audits (that presumably exist as per Cody's first comment) still get taken into account, or are they cleared too?

Comment: This not uncommon situation just makes me avoid the review queue.

Comment: @JamesThorpe IIRC they still count, so your position in the 2x fail -> 2d ban -> 2x fail -> 7d ban -> 2x fail -> 30d ban cycle remains the same

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Shouldn't your comment be an answer?

Comment: It happens unfortunately.  I'm on my third ban and both the second (which I got for flagging a duplicate which had close votes on it at some point, but the system decided I should have marked it ok) and third were caused by one failure and the second and third were very much borderline.  The audits do have several gotchas in them.  For some reason, my first time was for 7 days too.